What will ethereum price be in 2k25?
What will Ethereum be worth in 2k25? 

17k+  will happen even with 30% of chart complete.

The site is for technical questions. There are other pages more oriented to the crypto market prediction.

@ismael why are you riding my coat tail so bad?

It is nothing against you. The purpose of the site is to be a place for questions on the technical side. There are better places like reddit, linkedin, twitter that have more general questions. Also there more specific places for crypto trading.

It’s not twitter anymore it’s X lol. I ask a legit ETH question and if it got or not  answers oh well but if you can’t ask about price on here than i think that should be stated somewhere in site rules.

17k+ will happen even with 30% of chart complete even though I don’t know much 
